My website well-known folder is accessible from the web, is it a problem?
I am on my FTP and I discover the well-known folder. I understand that this is the folder created by Let's Encrypt, but I also see that by typing /.well-known/ at the end of the URL of my site, I have access to the subfolder and the files .
Is this normal?
when testing on other sites I cannot access them. As I know there have been attacks via this folder, I am concerned. Can you tell me what permissions are required to ensure security? I have 755 permissions on the well-know folder and also for the subfolder. The files are in 644
I already read many pages regarding this topic on the web but can't find the reliable information on the permissions to put on these files.

the whole point of this folder to be web accessible for the renewal process. you can delete the folder afterwards if you want

Set the .well-known folder permissions to 755 and the files to 644. To block public access but allow Let's Encrypt, configure your server. For Apache and LiteSpeed, in .htaccess, use:
<Files ".well-known/*">
  Require all denied
</Files>

For Nginx, add this to your server block:
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";
    allow all;
}

location ~ /\.well-known {
    deny all;
}

Don't delete the folder—Let's Encrypt needs it for automatic SSL renewals.

thank you so much, I'll do that ;)
